# How to get/work with HttpContext.Response.OutputStream?

Tags: c#, infopath

Any help will be appreciated!

We have some browser based InfoPath (admin approved) form with code behind.

I've got some business task, that when user types some VAT ID, there is required to check if the VAT ID is valid or not and return info as message box.

OK, I've used some web service call to [VIES](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl).

```
string dicValue = FormMethods.GetIpFieldValue(currentForm, formFields.PoDicIPField);
string countryCode = dicValue.Substring(0, 2);
string vatId = dicValue.Substring(2, (dicValue.Length - 2));

this.DataConnections["WebServices-Query-SOAP-CheckVat"].Execute();
bool isVatValid = FormMethods.CheckVAT(this.DataSources);
string notification = "This VAT is valid.";
if (isVatValid != true)
{
    notification = "This VAT is not valid!";
}
```

Then I've tried to send an alert back to page.

```
HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
currentContext.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + notification + "'); </script>");
```

[OK alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Oic.png)

And my problem starts after the user cliks "OK" at alert (loosing page content).

[Page look likes this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL6Jk.png)

Because when InfoPath form loads, it loads context of "FormServer.aspx" page.

When User Clicks on button, InfoPath form gets context of `PostBack.FormServer.aspx` page.

So I need to:

1. Store original response OutputStream from load
2. Send an alert
3. Rewrite `currentContext.Response` by original response from load

But when I try to save `currentContext.Response.OutputStream` in any object (for example byte[]), I'm getting following exception: "Stream was not readable".

```
        byte[] currentContextResponseOutputStreamBytes = null;
        using(Stream stream = currentContext.Response.OutputStream)

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            int count = 0;

            do
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);

            currentContextResponseOutputStreamBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Could you help me please with this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be pretty trivial here. You first invoke `dispose` on your stream object and then try to read it. This cannot work, because dispose 'destroys' the stream, so there is nothing more to read. This is why you get the exception.

To get rid of the problem, simply remove the `dispose` invocation. It should be executed at the end, not at the beginning! Moreover, you don't need it at all, because `dispose` will be executed automatically at the end of the `using` block.

Comment: Hello PJDev,

thanks for help. I've removed stream.Dispose(), but I'm still getting following error:
`code`'0x80131515'; 'Specified method is not supported.'
`code`   at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
`code`     at VytvoritKontakt.FormCode.Start_Workflow_Clicked(Object sender, ClickedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\lukas.chalupa\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\e5ff318f3b414d7b9915cdabbd61c39a\FormCode.cs:line 3748'

which line "3748" = count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);

Do you have some advice?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, now I see that the problem is more complex than it looked at the beginning. 
I guess that you get that exception, because `Response.OutputStream` is simply not readable. It seems logical, cause it's a network stream used for transfering data to the client - you can only write to it. Unfortunately I'm neither familiar with WebForms nor InfoPath, but what you're trying to do seems to me like a little 'hack'. If I were you, I would rather look for a way to either avoid the postback or make it return the same page as 'FormServer.aspx'.

Comment: Yes, this is a little 'hack' because I didn't found any other way, how to resolve it.
It's strange, that there is no OOTB method for this scenario how to do a routine action like sending a message box to page exept "XmlFormView.NotifyHost(string)" [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh278954(v=office.14)).
But I'm not sure, if is possible to implement Modal Dialog to FormServer.aspx page.

Comment: Back to this story. I would like to be able to know/see/track what is different in response, when I write to response the JavaScript with alert and when not.
Yes, I was thinking about the possibility to avoid post back, but unfortunately it is not possible, because if I eliminate postback, I would not run the code behind, which is behind the button.
You wrote "or make it return the same page as 'FormServer.aspx'" what do you mean?

Comment: This was just a guess based on what I'm used to in ASP.NET MVC, but this can be not relevant for WebForms (as I said, unfortunately I'm totally not familiar with it). In MVC, when you want to create a (sub)page, you define actions (which are just C# methods). The action usually returns view, which is - in short - HTML page that you specify. You can create two separate actions for GET and POST methods and make them return exactly same view.

Comment: Imagine that you have a page with newsletter. There, you have just a text input for email address and button for saving the email. When you first enter the page with browser, GET action will be invoked - and will just return the HTML with form. But, when you enter the email and click 'save', you will invoke POST (which is my imagination of postback in WebForms). In this action, you will save the email in database and then return the same view as in the beginning, maybe with some additional message 'thanks for subscribing'. I was just wondering whether you can achieve similar behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I might have to create my own FormServer.aspx and PostBack.FormServer.aspx pages. By default, when you create an InfoPath form, it is physically an XML document and XSL view that are part of the XSN template that you then publish to Form Templates in the SharePoint Central Administration. FormServer.aspx generates a form somehow. I do not know exactly how it works. However, when I try to add a Javascript template to an XSL view, InfoPath will recognize that it does not belong there and deletes the code added when I publish it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not add anything other than c # classes to the project. So, therefore idea towards Hacking... Nothing else I thought...